# LESS loop function not compiling in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

I can't seem to troubleshoot why a less loop function is not being compiled.  I've verified that the code works at both [winless.org](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) and [lesstester](http://lesstester.com/).  Here is the code below (I've shortened it):

```
@action-color:  #00ffff;  //aqua
@adventure-color: #000000;  //black
@animation-color: #0000ff;  //blue 

.genre-names(
  ~"action",
  ~"adventure",
  ~"animation";
);
.genre-names(@list, @index: 1) when (isstring(extract(@list, @index))) {
    @genre: extract(@list, @index);

    .@{genre} {
      background-color: ~'@{@{genre}-color}';
    }
    .genre-names(@list, (@index + 1));
}
```

the compiled output should look like this:

```
.action {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
.adventure {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.animation {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

It is sitting in `colors.css.less`, which is in the `assets/stylesheets` directory.  I've moved the code to different less sheets which are working and it still doesn't work.

I am using the [rails-less-bootstrap](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap) gem which is otherwise working correctly.  as dependents of this gem install i also have the following gems:

```
less (2.3.3)
less-rails (2.3.3)
less-rails-bootstrap (3.0.2)
libv8 (3.16.14.7 x86_64-darwin-14)
sprockets (2.12.3)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
therubyracer (0.12.1)
```

I've tried clearing my caches and sprocket files and precompiling.  The compiled code just doesn't show up.  Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but ruby `less` package `2.3.3`. seems to include quite out-of-date `Less 1.3.3` version which does not support a few things in this snippet. `extract` function in particular (i.e. `isstring(extract(@list, @index))` is always `false` there).

Comment: (Just in case you can try what `Less 1.3.3` is capable of at http://less2css.org (though this resource is not always accessible)).

Comment: @seven-phases-max that's it!  I tried it and I think you're right.  Thank you so much.  Feel free to put your comment in an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: So did updating the package to a newer version solve the problem? (If I'm not mistaken you would need also to update `less-rails-bootstrap` since `bootstrap 3.0.2` was also tied to `Less 1.3.3` (and may fail in newer versions)).

Comment: i haven't updated yet; I may not update because there is a very annoying change in the new bootstrap that I don't want to have (the naming of grid columns).  i tested the code in less2css as you suggested and i'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: I see. Well, since the loop is not quite necessary there (since you repeat all those identifiers manually anyway) - the [following code](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/6b725d8d9213184405da) can be used with `1.3.3` instead.

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes the next step for me is to create such variables from a string array via a loop.  but haven't found out how yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this on behalf of @seven-phases-max, who answered it in the comments my original post.  It was because the `less-rails-bootstrap` gem I'm using uses an old version of Less (1.3.3).